# PowerShell program, numbers read and change in a data

Tags: powershell

Why is 104 less than 84? ($matches.Values -le $counts) #Values = 104, Counts = 84 and why is 9 bigger than 84? And how can I fix this bretty?

Please ignore the few errors, are now corrected, only the one with the file name does not work yet and I would like to run around the file

To my little program:

```
if ($item.Name -eq "item.xml") {
            Write-Host "do nothing with this data"
        }elseif ($item.Name -eq "item.xml.bak") { 
            Remove-Item $item.FullName
        }elseif ($matches.Values -le $counts) { 
            Remove-Item $item.FullName
        }elseif ($items.count -gt 20 -and $matches.Values -eq "1" -or $matches.Values -eq "2" -or $matches.Values -eq "3" -or $matches.Values -eq "4" -or $matches.Values -eq "5" -or $matches.Values -eq "6" -or $matches.Values -eq "7" -or $matches.Values -eq "8" -or $matches.Values -eq "9") {
            Remove-Item $item.FullName 
        }else { 
            $safe += $item
        }   
    foreach($item in $safe) { 
        if ($item.Name -match "\d+") { 
            $matches.Values
        }
        if($matches.Values -gt 20) {
            $newFileName = $item.Name -replace $matches.Values, 
            $number;
            Rename-Item -Path $item.FullName -NewName "$newFileName" 
        }
        $number++ 
    } 

}
```

A backup is made with every change of my program, no problem until there are too many, this program should delete the backups from my server, because they are already pulled before, but the last 20 files should be renamed and not deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post in English.

Comment: Try `$item.Name -match '^(?:[^\d]*(\d+))+'`. On match `$matches[1]` will contain the last numeric substring within `$item.Name`

Comment: Thank you, its help me a lot, but why is 104 less than 84?
($matches.Values -le $counts) #Values = 104, Counts = 84 and why is 9 bigger than 84? and how i can fix this?

Comment: Because you're comparing strings and not numeric values. The returned results from regex capturing are string by default, even if such string exclusively consist of digit-characters. In a string comparison "104" sorts in front of "84" and "9" sorts behind "84". Use explicit type casting with `[int]` to interpret your capturing results as numeric values.

Comment: @Halfix thank you for your Help, the normal [int] dosent work but [int[]] I dont know why its work, but its work

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell PowerShell the type of value you are dealing with using `type casting` or else it tries to be clever ;)

```
C:> '104' -le '84'
True

C:> [int]'104' -le [int]'84'
False

C:> 104 - 84
20

C:> '104' - '84'
20
```

- [MS Learn - PowerShell Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-04?view=powershell-5.1)
- [MS Learn - PowerShell, Constrained Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-04?view=powershell-5.1)
- [MS Learn - about_Type_accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators?view=powershell-5.1)
- [MS Learn - about_Type_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-5.1)